# Highcharts not display for iOS and Safari

Tags: highcharts

I have a problem, I can not display the data of my Highcharts on iOS and Safari. Chrome shows no problems. In your opinion what is the answer to my bug? 
Thank you

Comment: Please elaborate your question more. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Could you please post live example of your issue like jsFiddle? It looks that charts from Highcharts demo web page works correctly on both Chrome and Safari.https://www.highcharts.com/demo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you are using `Date.getTime()` which gives you the time in UNIX Timestamp (Miliseconds since 1970-01-01)

Safari and chrome on iOS cannot parse such Date and you need to convert it differently to make it work both with Safari and Highcharts.

As specified in [this example](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-irregular-time) you can use `Date.UTC(year,month,day)` to parse dates for Highcharts.

Try this and let me know if it works!

BTW You do not need to sort dates anymore ;)

Comment: Hello Antoine Laborderie, I just applied your solution on my code and the graph display works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

[ISO Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/ios/demo)

[JS Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Kondaldurgam/fzeqx8dv/2/)

Use same as below code it's working

HTML

```
 <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; 
    margin: 0 auto">
 </div>
```

JS

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    type: 'bar'
},
credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: { 
            enabled: false
         },
title: {
    text: 'Campus Placement Preferences'
},
xAxis: {
    categories: ['BACHELOR', 'MASTER', 'DIPLOMA', 'DOCTORATE'],

     labels: {
         enabled: true
     },
     minorTickLength: 0,
     tickLength: 0
      },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    gridLineColor: 'transparent'
},
legend: {
    reversed: true
},

tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">
 {series.name}</span><br>',
                    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}"></span> 
    <b>{point.y}%</b> of total 100%<br/>'
                },
   plotOptions: {
    series: {
        stacking: 'percent'
    }
 },
  series: [{
      name: 'NO',
    color:'#70d8ff',
    data: [50, 30, 40, 70]
 }, {
    name: 'YES',
    color:'#1d3166',
    data: [50, 70, 60, 30]
}]
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I received a very unspecific error on Safari and also browsers on my iPad did not show the data within the highchart. I specified start and end time of my chart based on a function that used new Date(). After I read this thread [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results) I parsed my start and end date (specified in the chart options) with the given parsing function and now highcharts works fine!